# GAE Python application (User Services) error on Android Chrome with multiple google account associated

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-chrome

My following application works perfectly on desktop (all browsers including Chrome). On android devices, this works perfectly as well, on all browsers except Chrome.

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

On Android Chrome, this works perfectly, only if you have one google account stored in mobile.

However, if you have multiple google accounts created in Adroid, this application fails (only on Chrome) with following error, after it has asked for selecting the google account to be used for this application.

**Error: Bad Request.
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.**

This looks like a bug to me, since Chrome is tightly integrated with all Google accounts. All other mobile browsers handles it perfectly, since they usually store session data of one google account only.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good chance you are hitting the 2048 bytes request URL limit which Google App Engine seems to impose.

I just reported a similar issue on the Google App Engine Issue Tracker before figuring out there was such a limit. You can find my reported issue and a request to increase the limit on the links below.

- [Error 400 Bad Request logging in using Users API on Chrome for Android with multiple accounts](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11374)
- [Extend The Maximum Length of a URL](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7053)

Answer (score 1):

I was logged into around 5 or 6 Google Accounts when I got this error. After signing out of all of them, I was able to get by this error. I'm sure it has something to do with the URL limit mentioned in this thread.